# Create a folder shortcut in "My Computer"

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, windows-explorer, windows-registry, shortcuts

I'm trying to add shortcuts to folders in "My Computer".
This .reg almost works, I can execute programs like EXPLORER.exe, but I want to open a folder in the same window.

Can someone please point out how?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}]
@="SkyDrive"
"InfoTip"="Folder Shortcuts"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\Carlos\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\SkyDrive\\SkyDrive.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Shell\Open]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Users\\Carlos\\SkyDrive"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}]
@="SkyDrive"
```

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64

Answer (score 1):

An easier (and probably safer) way to do the same thing is to map it as a network drive.  Go to My Computer and click "Map network drive" (It may be phrased differently; I do not know which version you have).  Choose whichever drive letter you want, and for the location, put `\\localhost\Users\Carlos\SkyDrive`.  Make sure that "Reconnect at logon" is checked.  This will allow you to access the same directory as though it were a drive, so it will appear in My Computer just like any other drive.

Comment: I don't mind it being harder. And mapped drives show their own icon and repeat the disk space graphic from the real hard drive. It's cleaner with the way I asked for.

Comment: You can easily change the icon for a drive, and I am pretty sure that there is a way to remove the usage bar.  I just wanted to give another option that you may not have thought of.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not trying to be rude. Remove the bars for the mapped ones also removes them for the real ones, for which I like them.
I think that once I figure it out it be better for me just to create .reg files.

Comment: Somewhere, I saw a way to disable them for just certain drives.  I will go look for that.  Anyway, if you can figure out how to do it with the registry, feel free.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`explorer /root,E:\Setups`

replace `E:\Setups` with the path of your desired folder