# How to add a custom folder or an application shortcut in My Computer screen on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

As the question says it all I want to add my folder to My Computer screen as it has a long path in the hard disk, I don't want any shortcut icons on my desktop as I like it clean so is there any way I can make a shortcut on My Computer Screen like the hard disk icons? I saw folder2pc software but no support for Windows 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a folder shortcut in "My Computer"](http://superuser.com/questions/520202/create-a-folder-shortcut-in-my-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a shortcut on your task bar instead of the desktop. Create a shortcut of your hard disk on the desktop and then drag and drop this short cut to the task bar near the Windows Start menu.